# Colon (:) in url throws error on Azure Web app

Tags: asp.net, azure, iis

If there is a ":" anywhere in the url for an Azure web app, a 500.19 error is thrown. Example: `mysite.azurewebsites.net/:`.
The problem is that I don't seem to be able to catch those errors, and the errors are causing a lot of alerts.

The error is thrown before ASP.Net handles the request. I can even upload a web.config that the IIS can't parse, but the error is still thrown.

Comment: Another example of a request could be mysite.azurewebsites.net/foo:bar/